# How can the xenomorph from the aliens franchise see, hear, and smell?

Tags: alien-franchise, xenomorph

Has been on my mind for some time now, how can the xenomorph see, hear, and smell? When looking at this xenomorph you cannot see any indication of eyes, ears, or nostrils, yet it can still find its prey even when a decent distance away. If it did have such orifices to indicate sight, sound, and smell. Then wherever would it be located on the creature? If it does not have traditional organs such as those then what does it use to find it's prey? Would it be some type of organ that would cause it to sense any nearby life forms that were not of its own kind? or maybe does it have something to do with the telepathy between xenomorphs that let it distinct a human for example apart from its own kind? Or could it be that it's skin is special in which it can sense the body temperatures of other creatures like how the eggs do when they sense a life form near it that is not one of their own? Perhaps the xenomorph has a specific body temperature that no other life form could possibly have and maybe they have the genetic ability to sense body temperatures and if it isn't the specific body temperature of its own kind then it is concluded that it is a different life form that they must attack. Maybe perhaps that is why they react so violently to rapid change in temperature around them like fire from a flamethrower or liquid nitrogen? Any insight would be much appreciated from all of you. So please let me know if there is any official documentation of how the xenomorph has such ability to locate prey items and or hosts for the Young.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can the Xenomorph see?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/31648/how-can-the-xenomorph-see)

Comment: In the read animal kingdom, hearing apparatus are not always visible. For example, we know whales and dolphins have excellent hearing, but they have no obvious ears.